# Eclipse: While in C/C++ Perspective "No applicable Items" when trying to create a new project

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to create a new C project in eclipse but when I go to New, it tells me "No applicable items". Upon googling the problem I ran into the solution of making sure you are in a perspective. When im in JAVA perspective I am able to create new projects. Yet when I switch to C/C++ perspective, I am met with "No applicable items" Any reason why I would be having this problem?

Comment: Perhaps Eclipse-CDT is not properly installed. Go to **Help -> About Eclipse ->**, click the **Installation Details** button, click the **Plug-ins** tab, and finally click the **Provider** column to sort the list. Do you see a load of entries named **Eclipse CDT**? (I have installed **Eclipse C/C++ IDE CDT 9.4 (Oxygen.2)** on Eclipse Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2) and see 38 entries.) Also, what version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: You could also check Eclipse's error log for any issues relating to CDT: **Window -> Show View -> Other... -> Error Log**